# Magnific Popup will not work

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I'm trying to get the magnific popup jQuery library to work on my site.

See my HTML below; it seems to include the stylesheet and scripts properly. You'll notice I'm using:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

instead of the recommended:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but I have already tried replacing the former with the latter and it still doesn't work. Full html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/mystyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dimsemenov-Magnific-Popup-2ff1692/dist/magnific-popup.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond:400,600,700|Inconsolata|Indie+Flower|Oswald:400,700|Taviraj:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
<title>Zach Sedefian</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="top">
    <h1>Personal page</h1>
</div>
<div class="left">
    <nav>
        <a class="nav-link" id="link-1">About</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="link-2">Web</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="link-3">Music</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="link-4" onclick=>Photo</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="link-5">Contact</a>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <p class="main-p">Welcome. Use the sidebar to navigate.</p>  
</div>
```

I know this is odd I'm adding the relevant img / div HTML through a click() function, shown here:

```
$('#link-4').click(function(){
$('.main').html("");
$('.main').html('<div class="photo-gallery"><div class="photo-container"><a class="test" href="images/mosque-L.jpg"><img class="test-img" src="images/mosque-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/square-L.jpg"><img src="images/square-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/light-L.jpg"><img src="images/light-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/arch-L.jpg"><img src="images/arch-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/cows-L.jpg"><img src="images/cows-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/land-L.jpg"><img src="images/land-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/cascade-L.jpg"><img src="images/cascade-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/guard-L.jpg"><img src="images/guard-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/green-L.jpg"><img src="images/green-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/edu-L.jpg"><img src="images/edu-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/biz-L.jpg"><img src="images/biz-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/cal-L.jpg"><img src="images/cal-Q.jpg"></a></div></div><p><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/148227185@N05/">More on flickr</a></p>');
});
```

I have tried putting it on the actually index.html file but it also changes nothing.

I'm attempting to call the magnificpopup() function in app.js in various ways. The first is the way I'd like to have it, and the bottom two are the simplest possible ways to call it (also not working).

```
  $('.photo-container').magnificPopup({
  delegate: 'a', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
  type: 'image',
  closeOnContentClick: true, 
  gallery:{enabled:true}
});

$('.test').magnificPopup({type:'image'});
$('.test-img').magnificPopup({type:'image'});
```

Not getting any debug errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is the first time I've come to this site and not found an answer on someone else's thread. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `onclick=` in `link-4` is not correct. It would need to be `onclick=""` at the bare minimum (which wouldn't do anything of course)

Comment: If you're adding the HTML via click handler - `magnificPopup` will have already initialized before the relevant nodes exist.  If you want to continue to use this method, then call `magnificPopup` in the same click handler and wrap it in a `setTimeout` to ensure relevant DOM has rendered.

Comment: Take time and clarify your post as it currently isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!! You have to enter the full path.

```
$('div').magnificPopup({
delegate: 'div div a', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
type: 'image',
closeOnContentClick: true, 
gallery:{enabled:true}
});
```

Comment: Just beware that it looks like you are adding plugin to every div on the page. That will hurt performance on your site. Better to find a better selector and adjust your delegate path to suit

Comment: I suggest `$('.photo-gallery').magnificPopup` with `delegate: 'div a'`

Answer (score 0):

`$('.photo-container').magnificPopup({ ... })` will only work if it can find a class matching that selector. If you're dynamically adding that class after that line of code is run then `$('.photo-container')` will return no elements.

What you could do is:

```
$('#link-4').click(function(){
    $('.main').html("");
    $('.main').html('<div class="photo-gallery"><div class="photo-container"><a class="test" href="images/mosque-L.jpg"><img class="test-img" src="images/mosque-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/square-L.jpg"><img src="images/square-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/light-L.jpg"><img src="images/light-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/arch-L.jpg"><img src="images/arch-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/cows-L.jpg"><img src="images/cows-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/land-L.jpg"><img src="images/land-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/cascade-L.jpg"><img src="images/cascade-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/guard-L.jpg"><img src="images/guard-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/green-L.jpg"><img src="images/green-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/edu-L.jpg"><img src="images/edu-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/biz-L.jpg"><img src="images/biz-Q.jpg"></a></div><div class="photo-container"><a href="images/cal-L.jpg"><img src="images/cal-Q.jpg"></a></div></div><p><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/148227185@N05/">More on flickr</a></p>');

    $('.photo-container').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: true, 
        gallery:{enabled:true}
    });
});
```